# codeigniter activerecords left join not behaving as expected

Tags: php, codeigniter, activerecord

I have two tables that look like this:

```
Table_one


P_id     Value
1001     50
1002     54
1003     47
1004     65
1005     51
```

---

```
Table_two

S_id     Rating     t_id
1001     1          1
1002     3          1
1001     5          2
1004     1          2
1005     2          2
```

I am trying to join the two tables using codeigniter's active record class.  Here is my code:

```
$tId = 1;
$this->db->select('Table_one.Value, Table_two.Rating');
$this->db->from('Table_one');
$this->db->join('Table_two', 'Table_one.P_id = Table_two.S_id', 'left');
$this->db->where('Table_two.t_id', $tId);
$query = $this->db->get();
```

I am expecting this query to provide all 5 rows of data from table 1 with the values from the "Rating" column of table 2 appended to the first two rows.  Instead, I am only getting the data from the first two rows.  How can I rewrite the code, continuing to use the active record class, to get my expected result?

Answer (score 0):

Your `$tid` seems to be `1` in the where clause. This will cause only the values from the first two rows to be retrieved.

Answer (score 0):

If you want to get all 5 rows, you need to get rid of the where clause as there are only two rows in Table_two which have t_id = 1, which is what you're getting.

Answer (score 0):

By seeing your code it must returns 2 rows...if you want to retrieve 5 rows then remove where clause.